# Limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} x^{1/x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{1/x}$$
It's supposed to be calculated with L´Hospital rules, but I can´t find the way of express the limit as a quotient.

Comment: Use $a^b = e^{b\cdot \log a}$ to get your quotient. But L'Hospital's rule is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Write you limit as $y=...$ and take the natural log on both sides. That $1/x$ term then "comes out" of the exponent and arrives as an $x$ in the denominator. Try it out form there.

Comment: L'Hospital? What for? $\log x\to-\infty$, $1/x\to+\infty$, where is the indeterminate form? The thought-killing machine seems to be working at full power here...

Comment: The text of the question has just been changed (without any mention of the fact...). As a consequence, the limits stated in my previous comment do not apply anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT since the question changed:
$x^{1/x} = e^{\log(x^{1/x})} = e^{\frac{\log x}{x}}$.
Then you have:$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{1/x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{\frac{\log x}{x}} = e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x}} = 1,$$
where the last equality follows noticing that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x} = 0$.

Comment: yeah, I hate when that happens :)
I have just edited anyway, thank you!