# Help to evaluate this limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: limits, radicals

What is the value of this limit?
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{\frac{1}{x}}
$$

I have never encountered such a limit before, so any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the definition of $x\mapsto x^{1/x}$?

Comment: What is it, sir?

Comment: It is $e^{\frac {\log(x)}x}$, for all $x>0$. It's undefined for $x\leq 0$.

Comment: Funny. Why did two people up vote the OP's question in the comment?

Comment: Two people didn't know it either, I guess.

Comment: @Alex The thing is the up votes actually came after my reply to that comment.

Comment: Then I guess they're glad the OP asked?

Comment: See also 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092451/need-help-finding-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtxx and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105965/prove-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-sqrtxx-1-no-lh%C3%B4pital

Comment: @GitGud because it seems like he is mocking you

Answer (score 10):

Here's a start:

$\lim x^{1/x} = \lim \exp(\log(x^{1/x)})) = \lim \exp\left[\frac1x\log x\right] = \exp\left[\lim\frac1x\log x\right]$.

The limit in that last expression is a $0\cdot\infty$ form. Do you know how to handle those with L'Hôpital's Rule?

Comment: Yeah,I can take it from here. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Use the L'Hôpital's rule to find

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

An approach similar to G Tony Jacobs:  use the continuity of logarithm (i.e. $\log \lim f(x) = \lim \log f(x)$) to log the expression to get 
$$
L f(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}
$$
then show it converges to $0$ by L'Hospital's rule, then exponentiate back to get 1.